# Why the global variable is not working in the different functions in Python?

Tags: python

I'm beginner in Python. I wrote the code like as below just for practice.. Please look on it

```
i=1
def wrte():
 global i
 while i<5:
     print "%s .Line..\n" %i
     i+=1

def appnd():
  j=i
  while i in range(i,j+3):
     print "%s .Line..\n" %i
     i+=1

def Main():
   wrte()
   appnd()

Main()
```

Output is like as below

```
  1 .Line..

    2 .Line..

    3 .Line..

    4 .Line..

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  Line 18, in <module>
    Main()
  Line 16, in Main
    appnd()
  Line 9, in appnd
    j=i
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment**
```

Expected Result:: The next sequence is should be appended like

```
5. Line..
6. Line..
7. Line..
```

Please help me on this..

Comment: It's correct in `wrte`, think about what you are doing in that to make it work...

Answer (score 3):

You need the `global` definition in each function in which you use that variable.

```
def appnd():
   global i
```

Note: If possible, move global variables and related functions into a class.

Answer (score 1):

The next definition will work:

```
def appnd():
  j=i
  while i in range(i,j+3):
     print "%s .Line..\n" %i

# it would print infinitely, but will work
```

At compile time Python looks at a way variables are used in the function to define a scope to look for them.  In your definition of `appnd` it sees assign for `i` thus trying to threat it as local variable.  In my code there are no assignments, so Python simply get the value for `i` from the parent scope - in this case `i` is neither local nor global, it called *free variable*.  [Execution model - Scopes and Binding](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) - highly recommended reading.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you know when you should use global, otherwise it wouldn't be in your write function. You can omit it if you only read the variable, which I think you want in your append function, but you've got an i+=1 in it, so you do modify it. Just change append to do:

```
for line in range(i, i + 3):
    print "%s .Line..\n" % line
```

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
global i
```

before

```
j=i
```

should solve the problem

Comment: Yes this will work!
Every function requires "global" keyword explicitly let know that we intend to use the global variable :)

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your definitions are local. If you declare a variable as global in a function, it doesn't mean that it would be applied to all the functions. You have to declare i as global in your appnd() function too.
Having said that, it doesn't mean that your style is right. You would rather pass your variables to functions.

Answer (score 0):

In the **appnd** function, you must make the global variable **i**.

```
i=1
def wrte():
 global i
 while i<5:
     print "%s .Line..\n" %i
     i+=1

def appnd():
    global i
    j=i
    while i in range(i,j+3):
        print "%s .Line..\n" %i
        i+=1

def Main():
   wrte()
   appnd()

Main()
```